# HIVE, SELECT UNION

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I'm starting in big data, what would the union of two SELECT ... table_name GROUP BY in the hive?

```
+--------+------------------+---------+
| rating |    date_upd      | version |
+--------+------------------+---------+
| 3      | 2021-07-01 12:13 | 2.1.9   |
| 5      | 2021-07-01 10:39 | 2.2.6   |
| 4      | 2021-07-02 10:24 | 2.2.7   |
| 5      | 2021-07-02 05:37 | 3.2.4   |
| 1      | 2021-07-02 21:40 | 3.2.5   |


SELECT substr('date_upd',1,10) as 'day',
       count(*) cnt 
FROM tbl_one 
GROUP BY
       substr(date_upd,1,10);


SELECT substr('date_upd',1,7) as 'month',
       count(*) cnt 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY
      substr('date_upd',1,7);
```

Comment: `substr('date_upd',1,7)` does not do anything useful.

Comment: I'm cutting the date. * updated with the database

Comment: Could you please provide the desired output, it will help to understand the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get monthly count along with daily count in the same query, use analytic counts `count(*) over(...)`.

Demo:

```
with your_data as ( --Your data example, use real table instead of this CTE 
select stack(5, --number of tuples to produce
3, '2021-07-01 12:13', '2.1.9',
5,'2021-07-01 10:39','2.2.6',
4,'2021-07-02 10:24','2.2.7',
5,'2021-07-02 05:37','3.2.4',
1,'2021-07-02 21:40','3.2.5'
) as (rating, date_upd, version)
)

select  rating, date_upd, version,
        substr(date_upd,1,10) as dt,
        substr(date_upd,1,7) as mnth,  
        count(*) over(partition by substr(date_upd,1,10)) as day_cnt ,
        count(*) over(partition by substr(date_upd,1,7)) as mnth_cnt
   from your_data --Use your table instead of CTE
```

Result:

```
rating  date_upd           version  dt          mnth     day_cnt    mnth_cnt    
4       2021-07-02 10:24   2.2.7    2021-07-02  2021-07  3          5
5       2021-07-02 05:37   3.2.4    2021-07-02  2021-07  3          5
1       2021-07-02 21:40   3.2.5    2021-07-02  2021-07  3          5
3       2021-07-01 12:13   2.1.9    2021-07-01  2021-07  2          5
5       2021-07-01 10:39   2.2.6    2021-07-01  2021-07  2          5
```

Just replace your_data CTE with real table name.

Answer (score 0):

if your `date_upd` is a timestamp, you can use `extract` to get day,month, year.

```
SELECT  extract(day from current_timestamp())  ;
SELECT  extract(month from current_timestamp());  
SELECT  extract(year from current_timestamp()) ;
```

if your `date_upd` is a string, then you can use the logic you are using. But i think your `substr`is wrong.

```
SELECT  extract(day from from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('01/01/2021','MM/dd/yyyy'))) day_part;
...
```

Comment: I need to store the date in the hive anyway, but I need to join these two SELECT to generate a new output

Comment: i do not understand your requirement. could you please elaborate with some example - this is the input data and this is the expected data